# fetch id who have register all adv

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 3 types of adventures for which I used distinct function in query.
There is only one 1 customer who have booked all types of adventures.
The query i used to fetch the data is:

```
    select c.customerid,c.name
    from customer c 
        inner join booking b
            on c.customerid = b.customerid 
        inner join destination d
            on b.destinationid=d.destinationid
        inner join adventure a
            on d.adventureid=a.adventureid
    group by c.customerid
    having count(distinct b.bid)=(select count(*) from bid)
        or count(distinct a.adventuretype)=(
            select count(distinct a.adventuretype)
            from adventure
        )
```

Comment: Could you provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do it and share it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the customer ids using aggregation and `having`:

```
select b.customerid
from booking b join
     destination d
     on b.destinationid = d.destinationid join
     adventure a
     on d.adventureid = a.adventureid
group by b.customerid
having count(distinct a.advtype) = 3;
```

Or, if you don't want to hardcode the "3", you can use:

```
having count(distinct a.advtype) = (select count(distinct advtype from adventure)
```

I'll leave it up to you to add in the customer name (using `join`, `exists`, or `in`).

Comment: I will probably use join or IN. Thank you for your efforts

Comment: @Rajesh Don't use IN